# store xquery result value in a jscript variable

Tags: javascript, xml, xquery

Hello here is my problem:
I have a xml contained within a variable that is like this:

```
<channel>
<available>yes</available>
<label>CNN</label>
</channel>
<channel>
<available>yes</available>
<label>BBC</label>
</channel>
....
```

i want to use xquery to get the value using conditions such as below:

```
For Channels.Channel

where Channel/availability = yes

And Channels.Channel/Label = «CNN»

Return  EXIST(Channels.Channel/Id)
```

My question is: How do I execute xquery to return this ID value and stores the result within a javascript variable that I can use later on and pass to other systems. If its not possible please let me know how would you do to take a variable within this xml

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your example, but taking at face value I think this would return all of the ID values.

```
for $channel in $channels/channel
where ($channel/available = 'yes' and $channels/channel/label = 'CNN')
return $channel/id
```

To communicate with other systems, you could create a JSON webservice and return this to your JavaScript.

Comment: im sorry i am not quite familiar with what xquery can do and not do. From what i understood its mainly to display and format xml to html pages. once i get to the return $channel/id how do I capture this id variable and manipulate it in a way that i can return this to a javascript

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "return this to Javascript". Are you planning on making an AJAX call from JS to retrieve this data? Are you dynamically generating JS in XQY? How is your application supposed to work?

Comment: here would be the flow. I need a data in my xml variable that i will receive via a POST. this data can be found using previous xquery code such as for $channel in $channels/channel
where ($channel/available = 'yes' and $channels/channel/label = 'CNN')
return $channel/id. what i want then is use this ID value to pass it as a parameter to one of my javascript functions to do some other processing using this value

Comment: You may need to reverse your thinking on this, since you can call XQY from JS via webservice+AJAX; however, it's not really possible to call JS from XQY. You could kind of achieve this by 1) dynamically generating the JS in XQY, and assigning the result of the FLWOR to JS variable, or 2) In JS make an AJAX call to retrieve the values over webservice, and go from there.

Comment: How would idynamically generate jsfrom xquery any example?

Comment: The XQY would return HTML and JS, and anything dynamic would go within { curly braces }.

Comment: i think this is not really clear. I would have a javascript such as ` var myvarxml ='<channel>
<available>yes</available>
<label>CNN</label>
</channel>
<channel>
<available>yes</available>
<label>BBC</label>
</channel>'` then I will have an xquery stored in another javascript variable such as `var myxquery='for $channel in $channels/channel
where ($channel/available = 'yes' and $channels/channel/label = 'CNN')
return $channel/id'` how do i somehow manage to dynamically execute the code contained in my var myxquery against the xml contained within myvarxml

Comment: @Fongios The methods I described aren't easy to explain in detail in the comments. I think they would be better suited as answers to a separate question. If you really do want completely dynamic evaluation over webservice, then see my answer to your most recent question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178737/dynamically-execute-xquery-within-javascript-and-store-the-result-in-a-js-variab/16178880?noredirect=1#comment23127082_16178880