# dynamically execute xquery within Javascript and store the result in a JS variable

Tags: javascript, xml, xquery

Here's what I want to do:

**Execute dynamically an XQUERY contained in a Javascript variable example**

```
var myxquery = For Channels.Channel

where Channel/availability = yes

And Channels.Channel/Label = 'CNN'

Return  EXIST(Channels.Channel/Id)';

var xmltoparse= '<channel>
<available>yes</available>
<label>CNN</label>
</channel>
<channel>
<available>yes</available>
<label>BBC</label>
</channel>'
```

That will imply executing the var `myxquery` against the var xmltoparse and store the result of the xquery in another var.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by using `eval()`. But that will expose your webservice to injection attacks (and this specific pattern will make it really easy). This is why it is generally not recommended, ever.

However, if you needed to do it anyway, you could create an XQY endpoint that takes a string as a parameter and then passes the value of that string to `eval()`. The exact way to inboke `eval()` will vary based on your XQuery processor, since it's not defined in the spec. I.e.: In eXist, it's `util:eval()`; in MarkLogic it's `xdmp:eval()`; etc.

If you must use this pattern, then use every means necessary to lock it down: strong authentication, limit the capabilities of the user executing the `eval`, maybe even inspect the string before executing it.

Comment: is it somewhat similar to the xpath functionality such as var xpathResult = document.evaluate(
 xpathExpression, 
 contextNode, 
 namespaceResolver, 
 resultType, 
 result
);

Comment: @Fongios Yes, it's very similar.

Comment: wst thank you for this its helping me a lot. What i want to do in some way is 1.for a user to input some xquery script in a textbox on a html page 2. execute this xquery against a variable containing XML that is a global Javascript VARIABLE 3. get the result of this xquery and use it in some other scripts or send it back to the server for some server-side use. Do you see some workaround using eval? also if i execute this against an xml variable what is the risk of security as it will query only the content of the xml right?

Comment: i read again your answer. I will not use any webservice. I will use it in an application. No ws call. A page where i can input xquery that will be executed by the javascript and store the result of the query in a js variable. No WS. Also it will execute it against a specific xml variable. So there wont be any security issue right?

Comment: Your JS will call out via http: `http://mydomain/code/something.xqy?xqy=*xqy script*`. That is a webservice. Allowing a user to enter their their own script to be executed on your server is a very dangerous proposition. I would question the requirements of the application.

Comment: well this is an internal application that is not on the web and only for a few users. also i still have difficulty to understand why my JS has to call a WS. cant it be possible to have my XQUERY script stored in a JS variable and execute this JS variable using an eval and return the result in a JS without any WS?

Comment: JS and XQY are different environments. How is JS going to communicate with XQY if not by webservice? If there were a JS XQY processor that could work, but to my knowledge one does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for running XQuery client-side in for instance a webbrowser, I'd recommend looking into the mxquery based solution called XQIB (XQuery In the Browser):

http://www.xqib.org/

To my knowledge it allows calling JavaScript functions from XQuery, and the other way around should be possible too.

In case the idea of running XML standards client-side in browser appeals you, you might also be interested in Saxon-CE:

http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml

And depending on what you are actually trying to achieve, using XForms might be interesting for you too. It allows holding an (XML) data model within your page, and applying various dynamic evaluations. There are some client-side implementations, of which XSLTForms is a pretty good one:

http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms

HTH!

Comment: i want to do 2 things simple. have an xquery executed dynamically in a JScript using a JS variable containing the xml against i wanna evaluate my XQUERY expression